# return value if it contains text

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I am trying to write a formula to retrieve items from a column only if it contains a set of text inside it. I have been messing with a formula and it returns incorrectly and instead of skipping a line and just giving me the next one it places a 0 and moves on.
Basically, I only want to return the values in a column if it contains ".FC"
This is to narrow down the rows we will be linking to a flowchart without having to use the search criteria for ".FC" and just copying the column that way.

Edit: The ".FC" is part of a string of characters and will always be the last three characters. What I have now is
`=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".FC",$N:$N)),$N:$N,"")`
I need to add something or change something to make it so only the values that have ".FC" get returned and skip the ones that don't have it. This just makes it return nothing in the corresponding row instead of skipping to the next ".FC"

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1400155/edit) to give us sample data, expected output, what you've tried so far and how it fails to meet expectations?

Comment: Welcome to superuser. It'd be easier to help if you were able to post an example of your spreadsheet or what formula you're using that isn't working. Is ".FC" all that's in the cells you're trying to search, or is it part of a larger string of characters?

Answer (score 4):

With data in column **A** like:

[image]

In **B1** enter:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FC",A1)),1,"")
```

and in **B2** enter:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("FC",A2)),1+MAX($B$1:B1),"")
```

Then copy **B2** downwards:

[image]

As you seee, all the "good" values are marked with a simple sequential value.

in **C1** enter:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROW(),B:B,0)),"")
```

and copy downwards:

[image]

Comment: Woah, the `MATCH(ROW(),B:B,0))` is pretty clever.  I use similar type setups in a few sheets, but that's definitely going to be used from now on, thanks for that!

Comment: Not quite what I am looking for but it can work for now. I was hoping I could figure out one formula that would do the whole thing instead of two. By the way, the formula you put in B2 would work as the B1 formula as well. No need for two different formulas in that column.

Comment: @mrheineyboy  I tried the standard *Aggregate()* approach, but I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Nah. Your way is what I'm gonna use for now. Just had to tweak the formula and it works for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

Single Formula route:

Put this in the first cell and copy down

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,7,ROW(A1:A100)/(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".FC",A1:A100))),ROW(1:1)),"")
```

The main drawback is that this is an array type formula and if the data set is large it will slow down the calcs.

Comment: This one does work great. But you are right. It is very slow to run because I have a lot of values.